# regex python catch selective content inside curly braces, including curly sublevels and \n chars

Tags: python, regex, curly-braces

regex python catch **selective** content inside curly braces, including curly sublevels

The best explanation is a minimum representative example (as you can see is for .bib for those who know latex..). Here is the representative input raw text:

```
text = """
@book{book1,
  title={tit1},
  author={aut1}
}
@article{art2,
  title={tit2},
  author={aut2}
}
@article{art3,
  title={tit3},
  author={aut3}
}
"""
```

and here is my try (I failed..) to extract the content inside curly braces only for **@article** fields.. note that there are \n jumps inside that also want to gather.

```
regexpresion = r'\@article\{[.*\n]+\}'
result       = re.findall(regexpresion, text)
```

and this is actually what I wanted to obtain,

```
>>> result
['art2,\ntitle={tit2},\nauthor={aut2}', 'art3,\ntitle={tit3},\nauthor={aut3}']
```

Many thanks for your experience

Comment: If indentation is consistent - line starts with `@article{` and next `}` at line-start closes that article, you could also try e.g. [`(?m)^@article{(.*(?:\n(?!}).*)*)\n\}`](https://regex101.com/r/yqnGeq/2)

Comment: @bobblebubble Yes of course, you can also use the capture group and that will save you the sub for `@artilcle{`

Answer (score 2):

You might use a 2 step approach, first matching the parts that start with @article, and then in the second step remove the parts that you don't want in the result.

The pattern to match all the parts:

```
^@article{.*(?:\n(?!@\w+{).*)+(?=\n}$)
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string
- `@article{.*` Match `@article{` and the rest of the line
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\n(?!@\w+{).*` Match a newline and the rest of the line if it does not start with `@` 1+ word chars and `{`
- `)+` Close the non capture group and repeat it to match all lines
- `(?=\n}$)` Positive lookahead to assert a newline and `}` at the end of the string

See the matches on [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/bXoRl3/1).

The pattern in the replacement matches either `@article{` or (using the pipe char `|`) 1 one or more spaces after a newline.

```
@article{|(?<=\n)[^\S\n]+
```

Example

```
import re

pattern = r"^@article{.*(?:\n(?!@\w+{).*)+(?=\n}$)"

s = ("@book{book1,\n"
            "  title={tit1},\n"
            "  author={aut1}\n"
            "}\n"
            "@article{art2,\n"
            "  title={tit2},\n"
            "  author={aut2}\n"
            "}\n"
            "@article{art3,\n"
            "  title={tit3},\n"
            "  author={aut3}\n"
            "}")

res = [re.sub(r"@article{|(?<=\n)[^\S\n]+", "", m) for m in re.findall(pattern, s, re.M)]
print(res)
```

Output

```
['art2,\ntitle={tit2},\nauthor={aut2}', 'art3,\ntitle={tit3},\nauthor={aut3}']
```

Comment: wow, this is very elegant @The fourth bird. Thank you for sharing your deep experience

Comment: btw, i've checked (and discovered) regex101, is an exceptional tool. i was wondering if exists AI copilot for regex. since you understood exactly what i needed is it possible an AI with the same level of comprehension? e.g. the AI read my question-post and provides similar response than you. i've seen this `https://www.autoregex.xyz/` but seems to be much simpler

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
results = re.findall(r'{(.*?)}', text)
```

the output is following :

```
['tit1', 'aut1', 'tit2', 'aut2', 'tit3', 'aut3']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution for `regexpression`. It's not very elegant, basic.

```
regexpression = r'\@article\{\w+,\n\s+\w+\=\{.*?\},\n\s+\w+\=\{.*?\}'
```

aclaratory breakdown of `regexpression`:

```
r'\@article\{\w+,\n # catches the article field, 1st line
\s+\w+\=\{.*?\},\n  # title sub-field, comma, new line,
\s+\w+\=\{.*?\}     # author sub-field
```